# Answering community wiki on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, answers, community-wiki

When I want to answer wiki question which is about "technology gotchas" and I have multiple "gotchas" should I place all of them into single answer or should I create multiple answers?

**Edit**

Some examples:

- [What is the worst gotcha in C# or .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241134/what-is-the-worst-gotcha-in-c-or-net)
- [ASP.NET Common gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117/asp-net-common-gotchas) (I just noticed that this one is not wiki at all)

Comment: You should *probably* vote to close it as not a real question

Comment: I'm probably missing something. Community wikis are not allowed or this type of threads is not allowed? I found them really useful.

Comment: examples please. (sinister smile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These threads are generally not allowed. In the early days, there weren't rules on this, and people found "Give your favorite X" and "What's the best Y for Z?" questions to be fun, so there were lots. A convention developed where poll questions were CW and had one item per answer.

Later, the rule became "no subjective questions." That was relaxed recently to "we can have some subjectivity, but make sure subjective questions are great, as defined by [these criteria](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)." From the limited information you've given, it seems like the question you're reading does not meet the criteria.