# Why were restrictions introduced for Community Wiki?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, community-wiki, rules

Can I ask why the current rules/restrictions for community wiki were introduced? Based on my [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74033/answering-community-wiki-on-so) it looks like there used to be different rules. Community wikis were also used for capturing knowledge.

Examples:

- [What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net)
- [What's the hardest or most misunderstood aspect of LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215548/whats-the-hardest-or-most-misunderstood-aspect-of-linq)
- [What is the worst gotcha in C# or .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241134/what-is-the-worst-gotcha-in-c-or-net)

Those questions are polls - something that is not allowed. There are plenty of other such Wikis and my feeling is that they are very valuable - you can hardly find such information together elsewhere. So can I ask why were the new rules introduced? When we check pouplarity, upvotes and visits those questions lead the leaderboards. Community likes these questions.

**Edit:**

I skimmed through the links from the answer. When I wrote my question I was little bit dissapointed that Community wiki is not for community. Now I see that community is divided into two groups with different ideas about content of community wikis. I still stand on my opition but at least I know that there is also different (and probably superior) opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been a *lot* of discussion about CW, but here's the post that directly led to the changes:

[What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better)

It contains links to some, but not all, of the earlier discussion.

> There are plenty of other such Wikis and my feeling is that they are very valuable - you can hardly find such information together elsewhere.

Much of the debate is over whether these statements are true. Many people, like you, consider them to be informative/valuable; many others think they're "information junk food," which is kind of enjoyable in the short term but ultimately a fun diversion with no lasting benefit. Jeff Atwood, who runs the site, tends towards the latter category.

Jeff also disagrees with your second sentence; he thinks there are lots of places on the Internet for discussion of these topics, and he wants SO to be a place where people can get technical answers for technical questions. (I haven't looked for such discussion sites myself, so I can't comment directly.)

Comment: Thanks, I will go through all this stuff.